# Android app shared preferences empty after restart

Tags: caching, sharedpreferences

I'm having a strange issue with what seemed like a simple app to create (a thought that is always asking for trouble).

Basically the app starts with `MainActivity`, which the user uses to  'login' into the app. If successful `MainActivity` goes to next activity `ItemzList` by using the `startActivity`. This all works well, and once `ItemzList` starts, it populates its `ListView` with the list of strings from the `SharedPreferences`.

Again this works well. However if you then press the 'Home' button, and restart the app, when the `ItemzList` loads the list from the `SharedPreferences` the list is suddenly empty (which I've confirmed with the debugger and on my device).

I know it has something to do with the app being cached, since if I 'force stop' on the app, and then restart the list works again.

Am I accessing the shared preferences incorrectly?

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MAIN", MODE_PRIVATE);
Set<String> tempSet = settings.getStringSet("LIST", new HashSet<String>());
```

Comment: Where are you doing the loading? If it's in on Create it's probably not getting called the second time

Comment: In the OnCreate. It does get called the second time, but the SharedPreferences returns an empty Set<String>. I have confirmed with the file explorer in Eclipse that the MAIN.xml file created by sharedPreferences does have values for the Set<String>.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error. I processed the Set tempSet and then cleared tempSet after that (can't recall my reasoning behind that one).

```
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MAIN", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Set<String> tempSet = settings.getStringSet("LIST", new HashSet<String>());
    ArrayList<String> stringsEnc = new ArrayList<String>(tempSet);
    tempSet.clear(); //This is the erroneous line
```

I suppose clearing the 'tempSet' some how clears the list in the sharedPreferences object (but not the XML file itself), so if the app was cached, the next call to 'getSharedPreferences' just reuses the cache version (which has the cleared list?) Anyway removing the line fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

finally i found a solution , just put your prefs code inside async task and it will work , I DON"T KNOW why but it will work .

---

```
        prefss = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);

                new AsyncSave(favNamesList).execute();
```

---

```
private static class AsyncSave extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
        ArrayList<String> favNamesList;

        AsyncSave(ArrayList<String> favNamesList) {
        this.favNamesList = favNamesList;

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HashSet<String> strings = new HashSet<String>();
            strings.addAll(favNamesList);
            prefss.edit().putStringSet("favNames", strings).apply();
            return null;
    }
}
```